# Need help identifying pcb component

Tags: pcb, components

I was trying to repair the main board of a monitor (Samsung S27B750V), and after a few hours I did something I shouldn’t have, and blew this component.
I have tried to search for this but I am unable to find anything about it. Need to have it replaced. It reads “SOZ B21” I believe.

Perhaps there is an alternative to it?
I have a lot of old PCB's laying around, but have never seen this kind on any of them.

EDIT:
After uploading both photos I see they have different text in the middle.

Dimensions are 4.3 x 2.4 mm

[image: SOZ B21 component (Samsung S27B750V)]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! What capsule size is this? Your image appears stretched. Also, please zoom out a bit so we can follow the traces.

Comment: Can you provide an image showing a bit more around the component - making it easier to guess its functionality by what it is connected to :)

Comment: @winny To me it looks like a SOT89-5

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat - The parts have 6 leads if you look closely at the pictures.

Comment: @MichaelKaras In SOT89-5, the thick middle "pin" is meant for heat sinking and is connected with pin 2. It does not seem to count as a separate pin. I'm quite certain it is a SOT89-5, as there does not appear to be a SOT89-6. The package shape matches perfectly IMO.

Comment: Thank you for so fast reply. Dimensions are 4,3 x 2,4 mm.
Post updated with another image

Comment: Also, yes the zoomed in pics are a bit stretched. Cheap digital microscope

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat Seems very reasonable.

Comment: So far my best guess is that it's _some kind of_ an LDO. It does seem to match a common pinout, somewhat: 1–EN/varies 2–GND 3–NC/ADJ/varies 4–IN 5–OUT. As to which one it is, I don't know yet. By the format of the markings and package shape I've found it likely doesn't match Torex, Microchip, Diodes Inc.; but it might be a Seiko/NJR/ABLIC, ON Semi, or something entirely different.

Comment: Ok, so we think this is a SOT89-5, a ldo voltage regulator. How would i know what type to order?
It does not have power right now, because of a burned buck converter that supplies power to it.
(I was bridging the in and out pin of the broken buck converter, thats why this SOT89-5 is broken)

Comment: Nicely asked question with good photos... +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess it's an ABLIC S-1172B33-U5T1x low dropout regulator (3.3V).

[S1172 series LDO](https://www.ablic.com/en/doc/datasheet/voltage_regulator/S1172_E.pdf)

SOZ denotes the 3.3 V version and B21 is the lot number.

[image]

Comment: Very nicely done.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!
That definetly answers why it went. I gave it 14V..

Comment: @Andreas You are most welcome! Or should I say du är väkommen?

Comment: Now hopefully no 3.3v devices are damaged...